# zsh: illegal hardware instruction rasa init - Apple M1

Tags: macos, tensorflow, rasa, apple-m1

I have installed Tensorflow on the system. After setting up an environment for the Rasa, I tried to run the "rasa init" command and it gives me the error "zsh: illegal hardware instruction  rasa init".

I have tried several TensorFlow installation guides to resolve this issue but I am unable to resolve this issue. Any idea what should I do to fix this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7KBP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the TensorFlow version which Rasa Open Source uses (currently `2.3`) [doesn't support the new Apple M1 yet](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/7619). As a workaround you could use the [Rasa Open Source Docker images](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/docker/deploying-in-docker-compose)?